# Splitting a Date from hours and mins timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, I have a date time stamp. '2022-07-18 08:00:00"

How do I separate the day from the time? I want to group by the day, but cant because of the time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake you can use the [DAY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html) or [DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html#to-date-date) functions, e.g.
create a test table

```
create or replace table table_with_dates (ID number, DATE timestamp);
```

insert values

```
insert into table_with_dates values (1,  '2022-07-18 08:00:00'),
                                    (2,  '2022-07-18 08:00:00'),
                                    (3,  '2022-07-18 08:00:00'),
                                    (1,  '2022-07-19 08:00:00'),
                                    (2,  '2022-07-19 08:00:00'),
                                    (1,  '2022-07-20 08:00:00'),
                                    (2,  '2022-07-20 08:00:00'),
                                    (1,  '2022-07-21 08:00:00');
```

select the data grouping by the DATE part

```
select date(DATE), count(*) from table_with_dates
group by date(DATE);
```

select the date grouping by the DAY part

```
select DAY(DATE), count(*) from table_with_dates
group by DAY(DATE);
```

Comment: This just returns a single day - is there a way to return the date (year, month, day) without the time of day? EDIT - this returns days 1-31, but does not differentiate on the month. So I am grouping jan 1, feb 1, march 1, etc together as day 1.

Comment: yes, in this case you can use the "DATE" function: select date(date_column), count(*) from table group by date(date_column);

Comment: I added this option to the answer above for further reference. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest way is to cast to DATE

some data in a CTE so work against:

```
with data(timestamp) as (
    select column1::timestamp
    from values 
        ('2022-07-18 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-18 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-18 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-19 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-19 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-20 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-20 08:00:00'),
        ('2022-07-21 08:00:00')
)
```

```
select 
    d.timestamp::date as date
    ,count(*) as count
from data as d
group by 1 
order by 1;
```

gives:

| DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-18 | 3 |
| 2022-07-19 | 2 |
| 2022-07-20 | 2 |
| 2022-07-21 | 1 |

[DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) with DAY gives the same results, but is a little verbose.

```
select 
    date_trunc('day', d.timestamp::date) as date
    ,count(*) as count
from data as d
group by 1 
order by 1;
```

| DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-18 | 3 |
| 2022-07-19 | 2 |
| 2022-07-20 | 2 |
| 2022-07-21 | 1 |